# How to input a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, input

Usually, we input() a list in Python 3.X like this:

```
x = list(map(int, input()))
print (x)
```

But here let's say we give an input of 1234 then it prints:`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there a way that I can print it like:

```
[12, 34]
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: type spaces in between the numbers you want

Comment: Yes, but what is the logic behind it? Group 2 and 2?

Comment: It's completely unclear why an input of "1234" should result in `[12, 34]`. Is the number split in the middle? Is it split into chunks of 2 digits?

Comment: Consider splitting by , and input: “12,34”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want the numbers to be entered separated by spaces. First get the entire line as input:

```
line = input()
```

Now parse the input. In this case, split on spaces:

```
words = line.split(' ')
```

Finally, convert each "word" to an `int`:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in words]
```

Of course you can use `map()` instead of a list comprehension.

Note that this requires input such as

```
12 34
```

You can do this all in one line, but it is better to use variables to store each intermediate step. When you get it wrong, you can debug much more easily this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would not complicate things :
I would declare an empty list :

```
l = []
```

Then I would simply append the input :

```
for i in range(0, n):
     print("l[", i, "] : ")
     p = int(input())
     l.append(p)
```

You can notice here the "n",it's the size for the list,in your case it would be:

```
for i in range(0, 1):
     print("l[", i, "] : ")
     p = int(input())
     l.append(p)
```

We always start from 0,so range(0,1) would count 0, then 1 and so on with other cases.

Hope this would help.